# I am getting an TypeError in my python 3.x program and i dont know how to change it

Tags: python

I am new to python and programming in general, I am currently using codecademy to learn this course, however I have tried to expand on abit of what i know from the course and develop little ideas I have,  to help me understand better. However when ever get to this part of the code, it gives me this error.

```
  File "TeamSelector.py", line 12, in <module>
    print ("\n You have been asigned to team number: " + str(teamSelection % teams))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
PS C:\users\worri\documents\development\python>
```

Here is my full code

```
import sys

testInt = 64
teams = input("\n How many teams are there? \n")
print ("There are " + teams + " number of teams.")

totalPlayers = input ("\n How many total players are there \n")
print ("There are " + totalPlayers + " players to be selected into teams.")

teamSelection = input ("\n What is your assigned number? \n")

print ("\n You have been asigned to team number: " + str(teamSelection % teams))
```

I have tried many things, even having a seperate variable to do the calculation to pass it as part of the string at the end,  i have looked on google for different ways and whatever I have tried it gives the same error.  I understand enough that I think the typeError is having problems passing the float/int to a string, but i cant seem to find a .toString() feature, that I have used before when I tried to learn java.  If anyone can help me i would be most grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Are you gonna calculate team number by teamSelection % teams ?

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to the fact that your `teamSelection` and `teams` variables must be converted to integers before taking the modulus (the modulus operator works on numbers, not strings). When you use the `input()` function, your input is read as a string.

This can be fixed by changing the last line of code with the following:

```
team_assignment = int(teamSelection) % int(teams)
print("\n You have been asigned to team number: " + str(team_assignment))
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I have made a mental note that when using `input()` it will pricess the information as a string, and I must then convert it to the required data type  I have been banging my head against my desk for a while trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Always use snake_case to name your variables. [Please refer to this article](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/)

```
teams = input("How many teams are there? \n")
print("There are " + teams + " number of teams.")

total_players = input("How many total players are there \n")
print("There are " + total_players + " players to be selected into teams.")

team_selection = input("What is your assigned number? \n")

print("You have been assigned to team number: " + str(int(team_selection) % int(teams)))
```

## or else

```
print(f"You have been assigned to team number: {str(int(team_selection) % int(teams))}")
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to this?  I have come from OOP languages such as Java and C where the naming convention tends to be camelcase except in certain circumstances.

Comment: It's mentioned in PEP8 standard and its the python way of doing it.  If there is a code linter or a style checker with your project you won't be able to proceed further with your code. Please read PEP8 standards

Comment: @BeerHuntor I have updated my answer with a useful reference which helps you to excel in python

Comment: I was always under the impression that, variable names were anything and anyway you want them to be, following certain rules ofc,  but generally everyone followed the same naming convention for standard.  I wasnt aware in python that some checkers force you into sytelising your variable names. But thank you for making me aware, I will try and get out of the habbit. No promises though :D

Comment: Yep, but python gives the flexibility to do your own way.no hard and fast rules. Cheers!